# Size of an array of floats

Tags: c

What is the size of this array?

```
float a[10];
```

Comment: Did you even try?

Comment: Is your whole class taking a test right now, with the help of stackoverflow?

Comment: If I were a teacher I can't even see asking that question. Somebody who has never encountered programming before would guess 10, it's the only number there

Comment: @Mrozek often I realize that teachers do ask ambiguous questions. Here 10 (float) is perfectly reasonable answer, but I guess the teacher wants to know the size in bytes. Students should be a litte more "xyz" to "google" that a float in C is 4 bytes long.

Comment: "is sizeof(float) char long", as someone stressed that C std does not dictate single precision IEEE 754 fp nums for float

Answer (score 8):

It equals `sizeof a`

Comment: Unless you pass it to a function :-) But +1 for being right.

Answer (score 3):

Look for a C manual (*sizeof* keyword):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  float a[10];

  printf("sizeof float %d\n", sizeof(float) );
  printf("sizeof array %d\n", sizeof(a) );
  printf("array size %d\n", sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) ); // sizeof(a[0]) is the same with sizeof(float)
  return 0;
}
```

Hope it is not too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Have ever heard about [sizeof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof).
It must help.

Answer (score 0):

Enough to 10 floats. It depends of implementation. In most implemetations of C compilers float is 4 bytes long, so it will be at least 4 * 10 bytes. In C there is `sizeof`, use it!

Comment: A float is C is _not_ 4 bytes long. It _may_ be that long but it's not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: Doesn't C standards dictate the usage of IEEE 754 fp nums? 10*sizeof(float) is always safer and what I do, but I would have bet that float is always 4 bytes in all C standard-compliant compilers; would I have lost the bet? It seems so